# What does getText().toString() return?

Tags: android

I am new to Android. Please help me to clear about the code below:

```
String num1 = etfirst.getText().toString();
String num2 = etsecond.getText().toString();
```

String keyword is used for characters, but here its used for receiving the numbers.

Please explain about the dot operator and `getText().toString()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your title is helpful.

Comment: Look for existing solutions before posting a question. :)

Comment: i am new to this blog , so i wrongly mentioned into the title.kindly help me

Comment: code :      here num1 is declared as string for receiving the integer value.why dont we use int instead of string.i am completly ew to the android.please be patiece/                                                                  public onClick(View view) {
        String num1=etfirst.getText().toString();

        String num2=etsecond.getText().toString();
        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button:
                int addition = Integer.parseInt(num1)+Integer.parseInt(num2);
                tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(addition));
                break;

Comment: @yash soni ---as i said earlier i am completely new to android,so pls help me to find some book for understanding the code behind the android program. like (onclick,cursor,BitmapDrawable,getColumnIndex,getContentReso‌​lver)..thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, it's alright. You can begin with this:
https://developer.android.com/training/index.html
Watch the video tutorials and for any query, visit the same site and look up for similar questions on stack overflow first. It is highly likely that you will get your solution here. And contribute back to community whenever you can. :)

Comment: thanks for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are getting text from etfirst and ersecomd and convert it into string using toString().

[getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html): Return the text that is displaying.

[toString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html): Returns a string representation of the object.

Comment: thanks for the response. but still i am not clear,why we need to use string for receiving the int values

Comment: because we have to convert it  to string to use in edittxt and textview

Comment: which means edit\text format of the value is string. so we are using tostring.

Comment: Glad it helps u

Comment: as i said earlier i am completely new to android,so pls help me to find some book for understanding the code behind the android program. like (onclick,cursor,BitmapDrawable,getColumnIndex,getContentResolver)..thanks in advance